# Main-Class is not written to manifest of a jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf

when I create a jar file from .class files with either:

> jar cmvf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF MyApp.jar *.class

or

> jar cmvf manifest.mf MyApp.jar *.class

despite a line with main class in the manifest file:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Created-By: 1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation)
>
> Main-Class: MainClassName

I get an error when I start MyApp.jar

> java -jar MyApp.jar
>
> no main manifest attribute, in MyApp.jar

when i unpack the jar (in some other folder) with:

> jar xf MyApp.jar

the manifest looks like this:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Created-By: 1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation)

why main class line disappears? "MainClassName.class" is in this folder and it has main function in it. Here is the output when i create the jar:

> added manifest
>
> adding: SomeClass.class(in = 1106) (out= 472)(deflated 57%)
>
> ... other classes ...

Thanks in advance.

**[SOLUTION]** thanks to dave

> (Especially on Windows) Make sure the last line, here the Main-class: line, has a line terminator aka newline (LF or CRLF). If the last line is unterminated it is ignored. (Officially there should actually be a second newline, thus an empty line, at the end of the manifest main-section, but IME it works without that.)

Comment: In `Main-Class: MainClassName`, did you prefix the class name with the namespace : `Main-Class: com.mypackage.MainClassName`  ?

Comment: (Especially on Windows) Make sure the last line, here the `Main-class:` line, has a line terminator aka newline (LF or CRLF). If the last line is unterminated it is ignored. (Officially there should actually be a second newline, thus an empty line, at the end of the manifest main-section, but IME it works without that.)

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085 ! That was the solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Java 8, the manifest is written after the jar name:

```
jar cmvf MyApp.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF *.class
```

[Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)
[Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)

Comment: Nope; the arguments must be in the same order as the related options (e,f,m). Both of the pages you link to say this, though in different places. The _examples_ on the j7 page use the order mf while those on the j8 page use efm, but both versions support all consistent orders.