# manifest file not getting added?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I need to convert my compiled java program to an executable jar file, however I cannot for the life of me seem to get it to properly run. Whenever I try to run

```
-jar homework.jar
```

I end up with this error: "no main manifest attribute, in homework.jar"

This is how i created the executable:

```
cfm homework.jar manifest.txt homework.class
```

my minfest.txt file is formatted like so:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: homework
```

Both the class file and the manifest document are located in the same folder, so it should not be a pathing issue. All I could gather from searching around is that cmf is not using my manifest.txt doc when creating the folder but instead just inserting a blank manifest document or something.

Comment: This will seem like a weird suggestion but press the return key after typing the `Main-Class` line in `manifest.txt`, then save it and create the executable again and see if it works.

Comment: @Ankit+ if so, dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368363/main-class-is-not-written-to-manifest-of-a-jar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145327/manifest-file-generated-inside-meta-inf-is-missing-classpath-reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403139/getting-an-error-about-the-main-manifest-in-java

Comment: The return key suggestion worked. Thanks!